# How to dynamically change the capacity of a Static Resource in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I’m working with a AnyLogic simulation on emergency department. The departments leader want to test the benefits of adding, nurses, treatments room etc. It was easy to make it so that they can dynamically change the number of nurses through the GUI, as this is a "Moving" resource type. However, how can I dynamically change a Static resource type like ED-rooms which is tied to specific Network Nodes?

It's not that I want the resource pools to be dynamically created. But it's that I want to control how big of a portion of the existing resource pool that will be used. The current capacity is 13 rooms, and I want this to be varied from 13 to 28

Using get_Capacity(n) works for non-static resources such as Nurses etc. but when I use .set_Capacity(n) for a Static Resource I get the following error:

"(ECRoom is here referring to rooms in the emergency department): java.lang.RuntimeException: root.ECRoom: Capacity definition type should be 'Direct' to support this operation"

Comment: well. you are not defining your capacity as direct, so change that... and you are set to use set_capacity(n)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just pre-define several `ResourcePool` elements with static ED rooms linked to whatever node they would be using.

Then, set their normal capacity to zero and only change it to some non-zero value if the user wants it.

If you simply need to change the capacity at runtime, `myResourcePool.set_Capacity(someNumber)` is your friend :)

(Dynamically creating resource pools, home nodes, etc. is all possible but a whole different ball-game)

Comment: It's not that I want the resource pools to be dynamically created. But it's the how big of a portion of the existing resource pool that will be used. The current capacity is 13 rooms, and I want this to be varied from 13 to 28.

Comment: Yes, .set_Capacity(n) works for non-static resources such as Nurses etc. but when I .set_Capacity(n) for a Static Resource I get the following error (ECRoom is here referring to rooms in the emergency department):

java.lang.RuntimeException: root.ECRoom:
Capacity definition type should be 'Direct' to support this operation

Comment: ah, always tell about errors and what you already tried, saves us a lot of time ;-). Also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In that case, use my other suggestion :)

Comment: Contributor [@Oao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12821576/oao)—in an answer that will likely get deleted—has suggested that it should be `.set_capacity(n)` not `.set_Capacity(n)` in the event Action expression. I can't speak to whether or not this is correct, but wanted to put it out there in case it's worth consideration.